# Calculate the sigmoid function

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, sigmoid

I am  learning about machine learning from coursera. I am trying to calculate the sigmoid function and i have the below code:

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
%SIGMOID Compute sigmoid functoon
%   J = SIGMOID(z) computes the sigmoid of z.

% You need to return the following variables correctly 

g = zeros(size(z));

% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================

% Instructions: Compute the sigmoid of each value of z (z can be a matrix,
%               vector or scalar).



g = (1 + exp(-1 * z)) .^ -1;
 g = 1/(1+ (1/exp(z)))


% my question is why the first g calculation works for matrix(say 100*2) however the second only works for (100*1) as both are trying to do the same this.


% =============================================================

end
```

Answer (score 8):

Sigmoid function `g(z)=1/(1+e^(-z))`

in octave it looks like

```
g = 1./(1 + exp(-z));
```

Answer (score 6):

Correct answer

```
rt=-z;  %changing sign of z
rt=rt';  %transposing matrix

g=1./(1+e.^(rt));   %you need to use dot(.) while dividing and also while finding power to apply those operation for every element in the matrix.
```

Answer for your question

```
1.g = (1 + exp(-1 * z)) .^ -1;
2.g = 1/(1+ (1/exp(z)))
```

you have missed dot operator(.) in second function for division and  first function for exp() .

Comment: You don't nesessary need to transpose the matrix

Answer (score 3):

What you may want to try is to leverage the element operations (more info from Octave official documentation [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Octave_Programming_Tutorial/Vectors_and_matrices#Element_operations)).

Note that with the element operations:

> When you have two matrices of the same size, you can perform element by element operations on them

So as defined g and z are of the same size, the code below should return the Sigmoid function.

```
g = (g.+1)./(1 + e.^-z);
```

So essentially, it does 2 simple things. First, it turns the zeros matrix or scalar into one with ones "1". Then it divides each element with (1 + e<sup>z</sup>) for each corresponding element.

Answer (score 0):

.^ works for each element in the matrix. / does not. ./ might (though you might need to make some of the 1's matrices of 1's)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use for loops to apply sigmoid function to each element of vector or matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In the latter case, you are trying to multiply (inverse of division) a multidimensional matrix with 1 which is literally a one-by-one matrix. So it will result in a 'Matrix dimensions must agree' error for a matrix having more than one column.

Answer (score 0):

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
%SIGMOID Compute sigmoid function
%   g = SIGMOID(z) computes the sigmoid of z.

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
g = zeros(length(z),1);

for  i = 1:100,
  g(i) = 1/(1 + exp(-z(i)));

end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Following is the implementation in Octave:**

Please add following code in file name `sigmoid.m`

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
g = 1 ./ (1+((e).^(-z)));
end
```

Following is `Vector` example from above implementation:

```
>> A = [1;2;3]
A =

   1
   2
   3

>> sigmoid(A)
ans =

   0.73106
   0.88080
   0.95257
```

Following is `Scalar` example from above implementation:

```
>> sigmoid(0)
ans =  0.50000
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can make it like this:

`g = ones(size(z)) ./ (ones(size(z)) + exp(-1 * z));`

Turn 1 into a array with the dimension of z/g, then compute the sigmoid.